# Filter dataframe rows to return first two days, from date, for each type of fruit

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe is:

```
FRUIT  DATE           PRICE  CITY
Apple  11/5/2021      10     M
Apple  11/5/2021      11     N
Apple  11/5/2021      15     O
Apple  12/5/2021      14     A
Apple  12/5/2021      12     B
Apple  13/5/2021      8      C
Apple  13/5/2021      7      H
Apple  13/5/2021      6      K
orange 11/5/2021      13     L
orange 11/5/2021      12     J
orange 11/5/2021      33     H
Orange 11/5/2021      20     J
orange 12/5/2021      11     A
orange 12/5/2021      12     B
Orange 12/5/2021      29     C
orange 12/5/2021      20     M
Orange 13/5/2021      15     N
Banana 11/5/2021      3      A
Banana 11/5/2021      5      O
Banana 12/5/2021      7      P
Banana 12/5/2021      3      K
Banana 12/5/2021      4      N
Banana 12/5/2021      7      A
Banana 13/5/2021      6      J
Banana 13/5/2021      8      C
```

I need the rows of the first two dates of each type of fruit name like:

```
FRUIT  DATE       PRICE    CITY
Apple  11/5/2021     10    M
Apple  11/5/2021     11    N
Apple  11/5/2021     15    O
Apple  12/5/2021     14    A
Apple  12/5/2021     12    B
orange 11/5/2021     13    L
orange 11/5/2021     12    J
orange 11/5/2021     33    H
Orange 11/5/2021     20    J
orange 12/5/2021     11    A
orange 12/5/2021     12    B
Orange 12/5/2021     29    C
orange 12/5/2021     20    M
Banana 11/5/2021     3     A
Banana 11/5/2021     5     O
Banana 12/5/2021     7     P
Banana 12/5/2021     3     K
Banana 12/5/2021     4     N
Banana 12/5/2021     7     A
```

I have more than 100 fruit names.  How to write conditions for filtering the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if dense rank of `DATE` column grouped by `FRUIT` is `<= 2`:

```
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE, format='%d/%m/%Y')

df[df.DATE.groupby(df.FRUIT).rank('dense') <= 2]

     FRUIT       DATE  PRICE CITY
0    Apple 2021-05-11     10    M
1    Apple 2021-05-11     11    N
2    Apple 2021-05-11     15    O
3    Apple 2021-05-12     14    A
4    Apple 2021-05-12     12    B
8   orange 2021-05-11     13    L
9   orange 2021-05-11     12    J
10  orange 2021-05-11     33    H
11  Orange 2021-05-11     20    J
12  orange 2021-05-12     11    A
13  orange 2021-05-12     12    B
14  Orange 2021-05-12     29    C
15  orange 2021-05-12     20    M
17  Banana 2021-05-11      3    A
18  Banana 2021-05-11      5    O
19  Banana 2021-05-12      7    P
20  Banana 2021-05-12      3    K
21  Banana 2021-05-12      4    N
22  Banana 2021-05-12      7    A
```

Comment: Pls explain this line df[df.DATE.groupby(df.FRUIT).rank('dense')<=2]  .Can't we do like df. Group but('fruit') ['date'].rank('dense') <=2   pls explain difference in detail

Comment: Group but is  groupby() that is typo in above comment

Comment: There's no difference between the two in outcome. But the option in the answer will be faster.

Comment: Pls explain rank('dense') <=2   means

Comment: You can check what rank does here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682803/comparing-column-values-in-groupby-in-pandas

Comment: pls look into this question      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479119/calculating-groupby-sum-of-values-on-column-based-on-string-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of sorting and some basic data structures as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

m={'FRUIT': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple','Apple','Apple', 'Orange','Orange', 'Orange','Orange','Orange','Orange',], 'DATE': ['14/5/2021',  '12/5/2021', '12/5/2021', '12/5/2021','13/5/2021','11/5/2021', '11/5/2021','11/5/2021', '14/5/2021',  '12/5/2021','13/5/2021','11/5/2021']}

df = pd.DataFrame(m)

df = df.sort_values('DATE')

m2 = {'FRUIT': [], 'DATE':[]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(m2)

map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if((row['FRUIT'] in map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates) and (len(map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates[row['FRUIT']]) < 2)):
        map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates[row['FRUIT']].add(row['DATE'])

    elif (row['FRUIT'] not in map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates):
        map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates[row['FRUIT']] = set()
        map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates[row['FRUIT']].add(row['DATE'])

    if row['DATE'] in map_of_fruit_to_set_of_dates[row['FRUIT']]:
        df2.loc[len(df2.index)] = row

print(df2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682803/comparing-column-values-in-groupby-in-pandas