# comparing column values in groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe look like this

```
Time    Name    price   Profit   
5:25    A        150       15
5:25    B        250       10
5:25    C        200       20
5:30    A        200       25
5:30    B        150       20
5:30    C        210       25
5:35    A        180       15
5:35    B        200       30
5:35    C        200       10 
5:40    A        150       20 
5:40    B        260       15 
5:40    C        220       10
```

I want output should be like:

```
Time    Name    price  profit    diff_price   diff_profit      
5:25    A        150     15         0            0
5:25    B        250     10         0            0
5:25    C        200     20         0            0
5:30    A        200     25        50            10
5:30    B        150     20        -100          10
5:30    C        210     25         10            5
5:35    A        180     15         20            -10
5:35    B        200     30         50            10
5:35    C        200     10         -10           -15
5:40    A        150     20         -30           5
5:40    B        260     35          60           5
5:40    C        220     15          20           5
```

I need to compare between previous values of groupby is greater than of previous values like

difference of A,B and C are greater than previous values or not .
if condition matches it has to display Name :

from above at Time 5:40, diff_price and diff_profit of B  is greater than all previous Time column values

so output should print like :  B

my code look like

```
df.groupby(['Time','Price'])
df['diff_price']=df.groupby(['Time','Price']).price.diff().fillna(0)
df['diff_profit']=df.groupby(['Time','Price']).profit.diff().fillna(0)
```

Then how to do comparision between values to get desired output to display is :  B

Comment: So, you want the value of "Name" where the final price difference is the highest? Is your expected output a dataframe or the "Name" value (from your example, B)?

Comment: What's the criteria to select the output (B)? Is it diff_price or diff_profit? Because A, B, and C are tied in diff_profit

Comment: at time 5:40 if diff_price >diff_price of all previous time frames of 5:35, 5:30 and 5:25 then Name of B should be displayed with all values. And at 5:40 if diff_profit>diff_profit of all previous time frames of 5:35, 5:30 and 5:25 then Name of B and C should be displayed with all column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tackle this problem one group ("Name") at the time:

```py
# Let's iterate the dataframe by grouping by "Name"
for name, group_df in df.groupby(["Name"]):
    # Make sure that the rows are sorted by time
    group_df = group_df.sort_values("Time")
    # Calculate difference between each row (diff = bottom - top)
    group_df[["diff_price", "diff_profit"]] = group_df[["price", "Profit"]].shift(1) - group_df[["price", "Profit"]]
    # Fill the first value with 0 instead of NaN (as in your sample input)
    group_df = group_df.fillna(0)

    # Let's see if the maximum diff_price is reached at the end
    *previous_values, last_value = group_df["diff_price"]
    if last_value >= max(previous_values):
        print(f"Max price diff reached at '{name}'")
        print(group_df.tail(1))

    # Again, but let's checkout the diff_profit
    *previous_values, last_value = group_df["diff_profit"]
    if last_value >= max(previous_values):
        print(f"Max profit diff reached at '{name}'")
        print(group_df.tail(1))
```

This is the output I get for your sample input:

```
Max price diff reached: A
   Time Name  price  Profit  diff_price  diff_profit
9  5:40    A    150      20        30.0         -5.0
Max profit diff reached: B
    Time Name  price  Profit  diff_price  diff_profit
10  5:40    B    260      15       -60.0         15.0
```

Comment: display row that with all columns at what time condition matches like 5:40 b 260  35  60  5

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad added that change by printing the last row of the group (`group_df.tail(1)`), answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, compute `diff_price` and `diff_profit` based on `Name` column then patch the last group of time according your condition:

```
df[['diff_price', 'diff_profit']] = df.groupby('Name')[['price', 'profit']] \
                                      .diff().fillna(0)

mask = df['Time'].eq(df['Time'].max())
df.loc[mask, 'diff_profit'] = df.loc[mask, 'diff_profit'].max()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Time Name  price  profit  diff_price  diff_profit
0   5:25    A    150      15         0.0          0.0
1   5:25    B    250      10         0.0          0.0
2   5:25    C    200      20         0.0          0.0
3   5:30    A    200      25        50.0         10.0
4   5:30    B    150      20      -100.0         10.0
5   5:30    C    210      25        10.0          5.0
6   5:35    A    180      15       -20.0        -10.0
7   5:35    B    200      30        50.0         10.0
8   5:35    C    200      10       -10.0        -15.0
9   5:40    A    150      20       -30.0          5.0
10  5:40    B    260      15        60.0          5.0
11  5:40    C    220      10        20.0          5.0
```

Comment: i need to get output as B after matching condition

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect as result to show? A row, a filtered dataframe, the dataframe above?

Comment: Pls go through question , at time 5:40 if diff_price >diff_price of all previous time frames of 5:35, 5:30 and 5:25 then Name of B should be displayed with all values. And at 5:40 if diff_profit>diff_profit of all previous time frames of 5:35, 5:30 and 5:25 then Name of B and C should be displayed with all column values